# I'm unsure about how is my CAD related profession called

Tags: job-offer, employment

I am studying electronic engineering but due to my passion for 3D modeling I applied for drone assembly and within first few months due to persistent contacting with management I worked my way up through RND to position they called "junior mechanical engineer", worked there for a week and quit due to unrelated reasons.

Now, I am looking for a job that involves developing and modeling parts and assemblies in CAD software. Creating new mechanical and electronic parts in 3D environment for them to later be produced but when I search "mechanical engineer", I either get heavy machinery repair and maintenance or interior construction management jobs.

Anyone has an idea how 3D CAD engineer profession is called?

Comment: I agree with the answers that say you're doing more than CAD if you aren't simply taking dictation.  But while you might be headed toward becoming an engineer, if you aren't supervised by a licensed engineer, then you should avoid using the legally-protected term "engineering" for that type of work.  Designer and Modeler are good non-protected alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Google search for “3D CAD Engineer” results in plenty of vacancies for exactly that, as well as “Mechanical Engineer” vacancies in companies with names suggesting they work in 3D CAD design.

You could also just look for “3D CAD” + “job”.

Worry about the exact title a little less and about the actual job description a little more. As we all know “Floor Manager” can mean anything from actual manager of a store or restaurant to cleaning staff.

Answer (score 4):

Good answers already.

My addition is that it would help to specify your CAD software when searching for jobs. There's a huge difference between being expert at Blender versus being an expert at Autocad, or FreeCad or Fusion etc,. for example.

Also consider the end use. It's a very different beast to draw something in 3D than to it is to draw something in 3D within the constraints of a concrete medium or companies machining capability, or 3D printing,which again is different dependant on whether it's a filament printer or resin etc,. Once you start seriously modelling parts you need to know much more than the drawing part. And this is where the serious money is paid.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just drawing the CAD models, then the traditional occupational title is *draughtsman*, and overall it sounds like that is what you currently want.

If you're designing the models, including in ways that require real expertise and professional judgment in designing various terms and parameters that affect safety or durability, then a general occupational title could be *professional engineer*.

However, if you have no real experience, and your work is more about designing simple products end-to-end, and perhaps with the input of a little background in mechanics or electronics, perhaps a title could be *junior product designer*, or even just *craftsman* (which can cover a variety of wholistic production activities).

This is at least the case if you are employed for the task - if you were selling directly to market, you'd be a *small manufacturer*.

One kind of the "mechanical engineer" you mention is what would traditionally have been called a *mechanic* or *maintenance mechanic*.

The other kind, who works in construction management, may be a *professional mechanical engineer* who is responsible for supervising the design and execution of the construction.

Comment: It's more common to name a profession after what a master does, not a student. We all have to do menial tasks as our first.

Comment: @Therac, indeed but traditionally there were also apprenticeship or trainee grades (like "apprentice welder" or "trainee solicitor"), and many larger concerns have assistant or deputy grades (like "administrative assistant" or "deputy manager"). It's obvious the OP is not aiming at "master" level employment.

Comment: True. I'm suggesting it's common and well-understood that a junior CAD engineer is a de-facto draftsman. But in this day and age, staying a draftsman is no longer a career - it's expected to be a learning experience for a mechanical engineer. Not all will make it, but that's the expectation. So positions are named after the target job, with "junior/trainee/etc" added as needed.

Comment: @Therac, I agree. The draughtsman occupation was essentially deskilled by CAD, but because the OP has emphasised the drawing aspect, it was a little unclear what broader job he was expecting to be involved in. To be a novelist for example, you wouldn't say "I enjoy typing". Other than "draughtsman", I agree with the other answers that some job title including the word "CAD" is likely to reveal relevant jobs.

Comment: "Professional engineer" is not a job title, it's a license.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I've heard it used generically to refer to occupation, though not as a specific job title (because there is more than one field of professional engineering, so a job title for a professional engineer would always be more specific). It came to mind because the OP said he was struggling to distinguish his occupation from manual/tradesman occupations.

Comment: @Steve: There's not more than one field of professional engineering.  PE licensed engineers work in more than one field of engineering, but it's the same PE.

Comment: @BenVoigt, it may be the same licence, my point is that employers are likely to be more specific in their job titles, so that even though a person can fairly call themselves a "professional engineer" by occupation, employers are unlikely to seek a "professional engineer" but instead be more specific about a "mechanical engineer" or an "electrical engineer" (i.e. the very terms which the OP is finding have become somewhat confused). Also researching briefly, it seems the official term here in the UK is "chartered engineer" (although as I say, I've heard "professional engineer").